# Error only happening when adding ORDER BY

Tags: php, sql

Is there a reason why this following SQL Request does not work unless I either :
Remove the ORDER BY
Remove what's after the ORDER BY

Am I missing something obvious? I'm pretty new to SQL

```
SELECT Titre, Libelle, DateSpectacle 
FROM piece, salle, spectacle 
ORDER BY DateSpectacle ASC
WHERE Titre LIKE '%'
AND piece.IdPiece = spectacle.IdPiece AND salle.IdSalle = spectacle.IdSalle;
```

These two works :

```
SELECT Titre, Libelle, DateSpectacle 
FROM piece, salle, spectacle 
WHERE Titre LIKE '%'
AND piece.IdPiece = spectacle.IdPiece AND salle.IdSalle = spectacle.IdSalle;

SELECT Titre, Libelle, DateSpectacle 
FROM piece, salle, spectacle 
ORDER BY DateSpectacle ASC
```

Comment: `ORDER BY` shouldn't change the results you get, just their order. What do you mean by "does not work"? Show sample input, the results you expect, the results you get instead.

Comment: Order of SQL function calls matters; `ORDER BY` goes at the end of your query, not in the middle of it. Similarly, `SELECT` doesn't go at the end of your query, `AND` or `OR` don't go before `WHERE`, etc. Barring any other errors with your query, you need to make sure everything is in the proper order.

Comment: order by is after where, still try to uise JOIN instead of commas, there are sql standard for 30 years now

Comment: How do you run the php code? Usually when performing sql queries you can get an error message back. If you include the error message in the question it will be easier to answer.

Comment: The last query should not work correctly. It has no conditions relating the tables, so you'll get a full cross product.

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY DateSpectacle ASC` has to go after your where clause

```
SELECT Titre, Libelle, DateSpectacle 
FROM piece, salle, spectacle 
WHERE Titre LIKE '%'
AND piece.IdPiece = spectacle.IdPiece AND salle.IdSalle = spectacle.IdSalle
ORDER BY DateSpectacle ASC
;
```

Comment: simple as that! awesome thank you